# FTP timeout FIRST time

Tags: osx, ftp

I'm using PureFTPd on MacOSX (Snow Leopard, not server version). When trying to access the FTP account from the outside via dyndns (e.g. using https://www.wormly.com/test_ftp_server) the connection always **times out the FIRST time**. 
When I try **AGAIN in the next few seconds it works**.

What is this about?

I have forwarded the ports to my apple router and tried disabling the OSX firewall as well.

Comment: What ports have you forwarded? If it's 21/tcp and you don't have an FTP-aware firewall, you might want to try turning on ‘passive mode’ on your FTP client.

Comment: I have forwarded 20,21,22 and also 30000-60000 for testing purposes. The FTP Server switches from active to passive mode when logging in:

> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
< 500 EPSV command not understood
* disabling EPSV usage
> PASV
< 227 Entering Passive Mode

Comment: Is it possible the device running the FTP server goes to "sleep", and your first connection attempt triggers WOL event, effectively waking the device allowing the subsequent attempts to go through?

Comment: Hi Tim, good idea but that can't be the cause of the problem. I'm testing FTP access while the device is definitely awake. I guess the problem is related to the router / ports but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Is the problem still reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

Which firmware version do you have on your Airport? Try updating its firmware; there are many people who have reported problems with port forwarding in at least version 7.5.2 that are fixed in the 7.6 series.